# SharePoint Online Error while uploading a picture in Newsfeed. "An unrecoverable error has occurred. Please contact your system administrator"

Tags: sharepoint-online

I have the following error when I try to upload a picture in the conversation in the newsfeed.

[image]

I am unable to understand why this error come and how to solve this issue.

Thanks for all your suggestions and solutions in advance...

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the answer so posting coz it may be useful to someone else.

Increasing the size of the site collection https://myorganizationname-my.sharepoint.com resolved the issue.

Thanks

Comment: Was the MySite created? Otherwise that may cause the problem.